# Obtain the data from the first table and the data from the second table useful for connecting a third table

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have this tables:

```
 clients
     id - integer
     name - string

wineshops
    id - integer
    client_id - integer
    name - string

wines
    id - integer
    wineshop_id - integer
    name - string
```

I need to print on the view that contains all the wines the *name of the client* and the *name of the wineshop* referring to that wine.
As I initially needed the wine count to view it in the client index, I used the hasManyThrough relationship as the code below shows.

To be clearer in the **view where the wines of a specific wine shop are present** I want to see the following line:

***List of wines belonging to the wine shop (wine shop name) of (client name)***

Obviously as a title (h1), so not repeated through a foreach loop

*Relationship defined in the Client model:*

```
public function wineshops()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Wineshop::class);
    }

public function wines()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Wine::class, Wineshop::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Wineshop model:*

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function wines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Wine::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Wine model:*

```
public function wineshop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Wineshop::class);
    }
```

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('/wine/index/{id}', [WineController::class, 'index'])->name('wine.index');
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $wines = Wine::where('wineshop_id', $id)->get();
        $wines->load('wineshop');

        return view('wine.index', compact('wines'));
    }
```

I've tried this but can't work, I get the error **Undefined constant "wines"** when I try to pass the name of the wineshop into the view.

Anyone who can kindly help me?

Comment: In your `wine.index` view, search for the word `wines` that doesn't start with `$` inside a php statement. PHP is trying to understand that "word", and like it doesn't start with `$` (Like a variable), is trying to find it as a constant (And fails too).

Answer (score 0):

write the `return view('wine.index', compact('wines'));` inside the index function...

Comment: It is already in the index function